# Returning all object properties in Linq result selector

Tags: c#, linq

Having a significant number of properties in an object, is there smart solution to return all of them in the result selector? In my case that should imitate `z.*`. The other object `p` has very limited number of properties hence including them explicitly is manageable.

```
JoinedList= List1.Join(List2,
    a => users.ID,
    b => persmissions.ID,
    (z, p) => new
       {
       z.UserName,
       z.UserSurname,
       z.UserWhateverData,
       p.PermissionName
       });
```

Comment: `(z, p) => new {z, p}` ?

Comment: That return all properties, however they are embeded in addtional object of `users`. As a result I can use `JoinedList.PermissionName`, but for user related properties need to `JoinedList.users.UserName`. I would like to have it as a flat structure i.e `JoinedList.UserName`.

Comment: I think it is not possible to fetch all columns without mentioning names like sql. Because the return result is anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

use this syntax:

```
var JoinedList = List1.Join(List2,
    a => users.ID,
    b => persmissions.ID,
    (a, b) => new
    {
       rightTable = a,
       leftTabel = b
    });
```

You can put any name you want instead of rightTable and leftTabel.

Comment: This is same as @Guru Stron solution which creates additional layer of two objects `rightTable` and `leftTabel`. I am looking for a flat structure as per my comment.